# UX & Usability resources for web?

Tags: resources

I am interested in finding out about resources related to website usability and UX.
Also, if the resources contain examples, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

A quick list of some of my standard resources. There are *many* more out there:

For questions and answers on UX, there's this very site: https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Of different intent, but a valuable resource is the IXD site: http://www.ixda.org/discussion

An interesting list with examples of common UX errors and how to solve them: http://uxmyths.com/

A somewhat overwhelming list of links on UI design: http://www.theuxbookmark.com/2010/08/interaction-design/a-monster-list-of-ui-guidelines-style-guides/

And don't go too far without at least looking at Nielsen: http://www.useit.com/ After all these years the guy still prompts more arguments than almost everyone else combined, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, user experience design is a very broad topic, but here are some places to start -

- http://www.jjg.net/elements/ : The
  Elements of User Experience (ie. the
  UX Bible)
- http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/index.html : Particularly chapters 2-4
- http://user-interface.alltop.com/ : Alltop UI section (a smattering of
  news from various blogs)
- http://speckyboy.com/2010/02/01/25-ui-inspiration-and-design-pattern-resources/ : 25 UI Inspiration and Design Patterns
- http://uxmatters.com/ : Insights and Inspiration for the UX Community
- http://www.uxmag.com/ : UX Magazine
- http://www.andybudd.com/archives/user_experience/ : Andy Budd's blog, UX section
- http://www.deyalexander.com.au/resources/uxd/ : Dey Alexander's A-Z of UXD
- http://www.rosenfeldmedia.com/zeitgeist/ : Rosenfeld Media UX Zeitgeist
- http://ui-patterns.com/ : UI Patterns

Aw heck, here's my super huge list on Delicious 
 - http://www.delicious.com/ericawebdev/User_Experience